# How to fix surface normal for mesh

Tags: normals

I am developing an application that has to take STL files from users. However, some modeling programs seem to invert some of the surface normals. Basically some surface normals will be facing inward rather than outward.

I have to make a component that will *correct* the surface normals, and write these corrections to file.

Otherwise, later steps with the model will fail.

I have heard that the surface normals can be calculated from the winding information.

What is the best way to go about correcting these surface normals?

I am using OpenGL with QT for Window management.

Comment: I started typing up a whole big answer, only to find this which is way simpler than mine was: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26974/repairing-back-facing-triangles-without-user-input

Comment: Wow that's actually exactly what I wanted.