# Vertex sorting to match triangle list definition of an hexagon

Tags: directx11, vertex, sorting

I’m working on a project to display molecules with DirectX that I’m updating regularly to add visual effects. The one I’m working on is simple: display a flat transparent hexagon that match a substructure made of 6 atoms positions, as shown here:

[image: Molecules with translucent hexagons]

In most cases the connectivity of atom leading to this hexagonal structure is well known (like the one named Tyr56 in the picture) e.g.

```
  C2-C4 
 /     \
C1     C6
 \     /
  C3-C5
```

So I have built my triangle list according to this e.g. C1-C2-C3; C3-C2-C4; C3-C4-C5; C5-C4-C6. Note that culling is off to see the hex in transparent mode from either side.

Now my problem is that often there is an unconventional structure (the one in the center of the picture) inserted in conventional ones whose connectivity is defined but that not always comply with the standard one.

I have a protocol to display the hexagon based on the standard triangle list and I want to sort the vertex list of the non-standard structure to match my triangle list sequence.

This is where I need help to find a sorting method for the 6 vertices to match my triangle list, regardless of the order of the atom connectivity description. Currently I'm doing several tries to find the correct atom order, which works but is annoying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordering vertices of a face for correct triangle definition](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/182998/39518)

Comment: I have this sort of centroid method for displaying transparent square from 4 atoms but the sorting is easier. I will try yours that seems to be more general. thanks.

Comment: The point is that I don't have normal information required in this method. At the atom level we just have the  positions. And for this reason when I generate the hex mesh the normals are all set to (0,1,0) and my hexagon are not lit at the moment. I guess I can add a real normal after finding the centroid.

Comment: That's fine, you can take any three vertices, and take the cross product of the vectors between two pairs of them to get an approximate normal, good enough for sorting. In fact, you don't even strictly need the normal - just orthogonormalize the two vertex difference vectors and use them as the basis of the projection plane for your atan2 call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adapted the solution from the link provided in the comment.
Finally I have changed my mind. Instead of using a trilist matching the standard structure and trying to adapt my vertex order to this trilist, I use this method sorting vertex clockwise and then I generated a trilist in a more general way based on this clockwise ordering.

Below a result that works for me although I did not check with culling as I don't want to cull.

Using DX11 and XMVECTOR type with no SSE intrinsic.

```
PDPATOM is a struct describing an atom with position XYZ Pos and a FLOAT Angle
LPPDBATOM is a pointer to a PDPATOM struct
LPPDBATOM* is a list of LPPDBATOM
ACount is a DWORD for the number of LPPDBATOM in the pointer list

//sorting function based on Angle value
int __cdecl SortAtomDistance(const VOID* arg1, const VOID* arg2)
{
   LPPDBATOM a1 = *(LPPDBATOM*)arg1;
   LPPDBATOM a2 = *(LPPDBATOM*)arg2;

   if (a1-> Angle > a2-> Angle) return +1;
   if (a1-> Angle < a2-> Angle) return -1;
   return 0;
}

//function that create a temporary copy of the original list to work with
//use qsort to order the atom based on the Angle value
//at the end copy the temporary list to the original one
void SortAtomPoly(LPPDBATOM* ppAList, DWORD ACount)
{
   LPPDBATOM* ppAListTmp = new LPPDBATOM[ACount];
   memcpy(ppAListTmp, ppAList, sizeof(LPPDBATOM)*ACount);
   qsort(ppAListTmp, ACount, sizeof(LPPDBATOM), SortAtomDistance);
   memcpy(ppAList, ppAListTmp, sizeof(LPPDBATOM)*ACount);
   delete[] ppAListTmp;
}

//main function that generate a planar geometry for my needs.
//note that the geometry is expected to be flat convex and to be a tri, 
//quad, pent or hex or more but here limited to a hex.
//parameters function are ppAList : the original list of atom, ACount
//the number, Faces the number of poly to be generated (e.g. Face = 1 
//means tri, 2=quad, etc…

 void CGeometryDX::SetPolygon(LPPDBATOM* ppAList, DWORD ACount, DWORD Faces)
 {
    //calculate the center from the positions
    XMVECTOR Centroid = XMVectorSet(0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (DWORD a = 0; a < ACount; a++)
    {
       LPPDBATOM pA = ppAList[a];
       Centroid += pA->Pos;
    }
    Centroid /= ACount;
    //Get a plane equation from the three first positions. We expect a planar geometry
    XMVECTOR Plane = XMPlaneFromPoints(ppAList[0]->Pos, ppAList[1]->Pos, ppAList[2]->Pos);
    // Inverse the Plane, 
    XMVECTOR QuadXY = XMQuaternionInverse(Plane);
    //for each position calculate the delta to centroid and multiply by
    //inverse plane. Use the result XY to get the Angle representing the
    //orientation (clockwise) of the position from the centroid (radian)
    for (DWORD a = 0; a < ACount; a++)
    {
       LPPDBATOM pA = ppAList[a];
       XMVECTOR XY = QuadXY*(pA->Pos-Centroid);
       pA->Angle = atan2f(XY.y, XY.x);
    }
    //then sort
    SortAtomPoly(ppAList, ACount);
    Vertex V[6];//we want vertex list for hexagon shape : max 6 vertices
    for (DWORD a = 0; a < ACount; a++)
    {
       LPPDBATOM pA = ppAList[a];
       XMStoreFloat3(&V[a].Pos, pA->Pos);
       V[a].Color = XMVectorSet(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);//transparent white
       V[a].Tex = XMFLOAT2(0, 0);//no texture applied
       V[a].Normal = XMFLOAT3(0, 1, 0);//default normal
    }
    //for this application we will have only convex geometry so
    //generate a list of tris in a trianglefan mode 
    //(old DX7/8 trilist type) 
    //with point zero as starting vertex for all tris.
    //alternative generation of indices is possible 
    WORD IBs[12];//we want tri list for hexagon shape : max 4*3 indices
    //loop based on Faces param, 1 = tri, 2 = quad, etc... 
    //should work for more than hexagon
    DWORD i = 0;//incremented each loop step to turn around point zero
                //with increasing vertex index. E.g. 0,1,2 -> 0,2,3…etc
    for (DWORD f = 0; f < Faces; f++)
    {
       IBs[f * 3 + 0] = 0;
       IBs[f * 3 + 1] = i + 1;
       IBs[f * 3 + 2] = i + 2;
       i ++;
    }
    CreatMesh(V, Faces+2, IBs, Faces*3, D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
  }
```